# Syntax error when opening an Excel workbook using C#

Tags: c#, excel

When I try to open an Excel workbook I get a syntax error. Here is the code I'm using:

```
string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" 
                          + "Data Source=" + fileName + ";"
                          +"Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\";";
OleDbConnection objConn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
OleDbCommand objCommand = new OleDbCommand(@"SELECT * FROM Sheet1$", objConn);
OleDbDataAdapter odjAdp = new OleDbDataAdapter();
odjAdp.SelectCommand = objCommand;
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
odjAdp.Fill(dt1);
GridView2.DataSource = dt1;
GridView2.DataBind();
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

Because of the dollar symbol that sheet name needs to be escaped, enclose it in square brackets;

`@"SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]"`